# Changing the default OFS in AWK, is it possible?

Tags: awk

Is there a way to persistently change the default OFS in AWK form blank space to a tab? I find myself always having to specify the OFS when working with tab delimited files and I was wondering if those settings can be put in some sort of dotfile?

The closest I have seen is just to create an alias ( `alias awkt='awk -v OFS="\t"'` ), which I guess it does the job, but I still would like to know if awk can be customized by providing some sort of dotfile.

Comment: No, awk doesn't do dotfiles. nor does it evaluate environment variables other than `AWKPATH`, `AWKLIBPATH` and a few others listed under `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES` in the man-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short answer is NO, since AWK does not have config files, so you cannot set a default "within" a config for AWK.

You will either have to setup an alias or a function to do this for you, or set it in the command line every time.